# ASP.net C# Return JS Alert from another thread

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, multithreading

I have the following case:

in Default.aspx.cs

```
void Button1_Click(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
  new Thread(() =>LongProcessFunction()).Start(); 
  // I am running this function in a new thread so the end user does not wait till the end of the process
}

public void LongProcessFunction()
{
  //some code with long process
  // When done alert the user no matter what he's doing on the website.
  System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Alert","alert('Function is Complete')" , true);    
}
```

The problem is that I need this alert script to show for end user.
I am assuming that it's running on the other thread and not showing.

Comment: How long is long running? If it is not too long you can make an ajax request.

Comment: It is a very long data export function , takes 38 seconds to 40 and User doesn't really have to wait for it, he's exporting data to another DB !

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a session or application variable at the end of your long running function, which indicates that the process has finished. You could then check if this variable has been set on each page load (ideally in a base class which inherits from Page) and, if it has been set, unset it and call your RegisterStartupScript code.

Comment: Hello Lan,
Actually that's what I have done so far. I have assigned a static variable and on the masterPage_load i tested if the static variable is "" or has message and then reset the static variable to be "" again. This will work only if postback happens. in my case user might not do anything that might causes postback, and I can't force postback because I might interrupt the user action. I was thinking of implementing a timer in the masterpage and do the test of the static message on Tick but did not work for some reason! any idea ?